# Exit command prompt after processing in a console application

Tags: c#

I have the following command to run a task from scheduler which is a console application:

```
  ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            psi.Arguments = string.Format("/K SCHTASKS.EXE /Change /TN \"{0}\" /DISABLE", this.FullTaskName);
            Process.Start(psi);
```

Now I want to close the command prompt after executing the task. I tried,

```
  Environment.Exit(0);
```

but this termiantes the process and doesnot close the command prompt opened. I need to Exit the command prompt after running the task.

Comment: Why `/K` is used here? Why not call `SCHTASKS.EXE` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do net to invoke `SCHTASKS.EXE` using `cmd.exe` you can do the following

```csharp
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        psi.Arguments = string.Format("/K SCHTASKS.EXE /Change /TN \"{0}\" /DISABLE & exit", this.FullTaskName);
        Process.Start(psi);
```

Please note the addition of `& exit`. `&` allows you to concatenate multiple commands to be executed in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `/k` switch, you are asking the Command Prompt window to stay open. Use `/c` instead:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
psi.Arguments = string.Format("/C SCHTASKS.EXE /Change /TN \"{0}\" /DISABLE", this.FullTaskName);
Process.Start(psi);
```

**But why call `cmd.exe` anyway? Call `SchTasks.exe` directly.**